# You can flag your own chat messages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

I can flag messages I posted myself in chat. How can this be right?

I just clicked flag, wrote "test" and clicked OK, and was told that you will take a look at it.

Please take a better look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a common request to be able to flag your own posts for moderator attention -- if you need a moderator to look at it for some reason.

Comment: So why not comments too? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124751/166155