# Immediately delete if mod flags as "not an answer"

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, deleted-answers

I like the idea of keeping a paper trail of moderation decisions by using flags. This works ([more or less](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210985/156248)) nicely with comments and there is no reason not to do it with answers.

So if I find an answer post that is not an answer, I flag as "not an answer" and then delete it.

Since there is no reason for keeping non-answers around, please make the deletion automatic for mods in this case.

Comment: Regarding the request itself, why do you (as moderator) cast a NAA flag in the first place? What purpose does it serve? Flags are meant to bring moderator attention, so since you are already the moderator you're expected to act, not cast another flag. I guess you mean the "paper trail of moderation decisions", but I think it would be better to further explain what it means and what are its benefits.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It seems the point of the question is that simply clicking "delete" does not leave any record of *why* the moderator decided to delete. This is only the case when a moderator finds a problematic post by himself,  not by handling flags.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier so comment like "This is not a true/full answer" will serve the same goal, plus be visible to 10k users, not only to other moderators.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's a reasonable workaround. By the way, NAA flags don't go just to moderators, they are also processed by LQ review queue. One can imagine a moderator finding something that looks like NAA, but so far from his area of expertise that it's hard to tell. (I imagine finding a weirdly complicated math formula given without context: it may be a badly presented answer, or total BS.)  in such a case, it may be reasonable for a mod to flag NAA to put the answer through review. (And this may be an argument against the feature request.)

Comment: @Thisismuch eh, Monica stole your credit and fame. ;-)

Comment: Oh sorry @Thisismuchhealthier., I didn't see your comment.  But I guess I'm not *too* sorry, because you could have put it in an answer. :-)  (Maybe you didn't because you were speculating.  I can say from experience that yes, your speculation is correct.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio No need to be sorry; it's better to hear from someone who actually does this. And you phrased it better.

Comment: The answer should be paper trail enough :/

Comment: You realize we log all of your deletions, right? Any other moderator can view a list of them, and even 10K users, given a link to the answer, will see your name. If it's not obvious why you deleted, then you should probably be leaving a comment...

Comment: @Shog9: I do the comment thing now, mostly, but I figured using the flag is faster and cleaner.

Comment: Not really. Then when a 10K user asks you gotta explain it to them. And when the author emails us, we gotta explain it to them. Really just adds overhead. Get that pro forma comments script, makes this sorta thing quick'n painless - looking at just building that into the delete button for mods.

Comment: @Shog9: So maybe answers (and questions, for that matter) should indicate the deletion reason for more than just mods (or at all)? Kidding, I get your point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a moderator I have sometimes seen things that look like NAA, but it's not an area I'm particularly strong in and I worry that I might be missing something.  Currently I flag those as NAA to send them to the review queue and get input.  With your change, I would have to instead bring it up on meta or in chat, which (a) is more work and (b) can prejudice the results (people might be more inclined to go along with it because it came from a mod).

When I want an audit trail (and I use flags for that too), I don't have a problem with flagging and then deleting.  It's one more mouse click, not a whole new page-load or dialogue.  Your proposal is mildly more convenient for one use case but completely breaks another; the status quo is a little less convenient but works for both cases.

Comment: Fair enough; more flexibility seems to be needed than I could see. Thanks!

Comment: Yup; I definitely like the ability to put in flags that aren't auto-handled. Spam/Offensive being the only exception.

Comment: And on the other hand, *comment* flags auto-handle -- which makes perfect sense to me, as there's no queue to send them to.  So if I want input before deleting a comment, I have to ask outside the flagging system anyway.  (Not that that comes up a lot...)

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato Arguably, "offensive" is (one of) the most subjective flags

Comment: @Raphael I think most of us would use that extremely sparingly, really. In fact, I don't know that we ever use those flags to begin with; we tend to simply delete. The only reason for us to flag instead of delete for those two would be to apply the 100pt penalty, but I don't think that's something we'd tend to do.