# Flagging your own comment for attention

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags

Consider *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965796/i-am-new-to-learn-c-programming-please-help-me-out*.

I've left a comment, but I have misspelled a word: complement. I'm always doing that. But I'm a proud cat who likes to regard themselves as a linchpin for literacy.

Ideally I'd like to edit my comment and make the correction, but I can't do that due to the editing rule of 5 minutes for a comment. I understand that's a good rule *most of the time*.

So ideally I'd ask a moderator to edit it. The only problem being that I can't flag my own comment.

Besides my attending a spelling lesson, does anyone have any thoughts on how we could support this? I think my comment is valuable, so I don't want to remove it. Of course, I could delete and reinsert the comment with the correct spelling, but sometimes that can compromise the comment flow.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124751/allow-flagging-own-comments (not dupe since it's a feature request, not just asking if it's possible or not)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: yes, that's helpful. Tempted to close this as a dupe. The sentiment is similar

Comment: You could do it yourself, but here you go. :)

Answer (score 6):

Moderators won't edit comments for minor spelling mistakes, especially on SO they're rather busy. Having the limited number of moderators editing spelling mistakes in comments wouldn't scale.

Small mistakes in comments simply don't matter all that much, just ignore them or use the mentioned workaround.